# How to group items get from DB by hours range?

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, api

I have to return from my API a list of time ranges and all items sold in that ranges.

I have made a query which returns all items with the range in hours in which it has been sold, the query returns data like:

```
DESCRIPTION|QUANTITY|PRICE|HOURS
TEST        1        1.12  0:00-01:00
TOST        5        1.12  0:00-01:00
TIST        8        1.12  8:00-09:00
TAST        2        1.12  8:00-09:00
TAST        2        1.12  8:00-09:00
TAST        2        1.12  9:00-10:00
TAST        2        1.12  10:00-11:00
```

And i would return from my API a data like

```
 [{ "range": "0:00-01:00", "items": [{"desc": "TEST", "qta": 8, "price": 1.12}, {"desc": "TOST", "qta": 8, "price": 1.12}, ...]}, {"range": "08:00-09:00", "items": [{"desc": "TIST", "qta": 8, "price": 1.12}]} ...]
```

So i have made my model (it has more data as the data above is just an example)

```
Public Class FasceOrarie

    Public Property fascia As String
    Public Property articoli As IEnumerable(Of ArticoliFascia)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(fascia As String, articoli As IEnumerable(Of ArticoliFascia))

        Me.fascia = fascia
        Me.articoli = articoli

    End Sub
    Public Class ArticoliFascia

        Public Property codart As String
        Public Property desc As String
        Public Property qta As String
        Public Property importo As String

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(codart As String, desc As String, qta As Double, importo As Double)

            Me.codart = codart
            Me.desc = desc
            Me.qta = qta
            Me.importo = importo

        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

And here i have my function where i make my select and i have the reader with all data:

```
Public Function ArticoliFasciaOraria(db As String) As IEnumerable(Of FasceOrarie)
    Dim SQLConnect As String = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=" & db & ";Uid=visuali;Pwd=visualintelligence2k20;"
    Dim queryFasce As String = "MYQUERY"
    Dim listArticoli As List(Of FasceOrarie)

    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(queryFasce, cn)
            Try
                Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    // how to add data properly in the list of FasceOrarie?
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

But how can i format my data to set it properly in my model? if i will just add it to the list i will have same ranges set multiple times in the array while i would have to have one range with all items that belong to that range in it...

I will accept even c# solutions as i will migrate later that project to c#

Comment: You can create a dictionary where the Key is the range value and the Value is an element of type FasceOrarie. Inside the loop check of the key exists in the dictionary. If not then add a new element with an initial value from your record, if yes, sum the quantity of the current record to the existing value. Of course if this logic could be added directly to the query it would be a lot better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in the following way:

```
Public Function ArticoliFasciaOraria(config As ModelConfig.Config, db As String) As IEnumerable(Of FasceOrarie)
    Dim SQLConnect As String = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=" & db & ";Uid=visuali;Pwd=visualintelligence2k20;"
    Dim where As String = ModelConfig.QueryParametri(config.config, "SC", False)
    Dim queryFasce As String = "XXX;"

    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(queryFasce, cn)
            Try
                Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim fasce As List(Of FasceOrarie) = New List(Of FasceOrarie)
                    While reader.Read()
                        Dim fasciaOraria = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.Item("ORE"))
                        Dim fascia = (From f In fasce Where f.fascia = fasciaOraria).FirstOrDefault

                        If fascia IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim qta As Double = reader.Item("QTA")
                            Dim importo As Double = reader.Item("IMPORTO")
                            If qta > 0 And importo > 0 Then
                                fascia.articoli.Add(New ArticoliFascia(reader.Item("CODART"), reader.Item("DESCRIZIONE"), qta, importo))
                            End If
                        Else
                            fasce.Add(New FasceOrarie(fasciaOraria, New List(Of ArticoliFascia)))
                        End If

                    End While
                    Return fasce
                End Using
            Catch
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

First of all i initialize an empty array of FasceOrarie, then in the while i get the string with the hours range get from DB and check if it exists in my array of FasceOrarie by doing a select using LINQ on the array list.

If the value exist in the array i add to it's list of items the new item, else i create a new item in the array list with that hours range.

Comment: You are comparing strings not numbers (dates).  So if you sort you will have 1PM, 10PM, 11PM, 12PM, 2PM.  Also you are only looking at start time and ranges may not always be 1 hour.

Comment: i sort the data in the DB query and actually the time is got from a concat in the query where i get only the hours so the returned value from the DB is always formatted as "HH:00-HH:00" and it's a string

Answer (score 2):

Posting is tagged with c# so here is my recommendations :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;



namespace ConsoleApplication186
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION",typeof(string)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("QUANTITY",typeof(int)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("PRICE",typeof(decimal)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("HOURS",typeof(string)); 

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TEST", 1, 1.12, "0:00-01:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TOST", 5, 1.12, "0:00-01:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TIST", 8, 1.12, "8:00-09:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TAST", 2, 1.12, "8:00-09:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TAST", 2, 1.12, "8:00-09:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TAST", 2, 1.12, "9:00-10:00"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"TAST", 2, 1.12, "10:00-11:00"});

            List<ArticoliFascia> articoliFascia = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ArticoliFascia(x.Field<string>(3), x.Field<string>(0), x.Field<int>(1), x.Field<decimal>(2))).ToList();

            var groups = articoliFascia.GroupBy(x => new { start = x.startTime, end = x.endTime }).ToList();


 
        }
    }
    public class ArticoliFascia
    {
        public string codart { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public int qta { get; set; }
        public decimal importo { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan startTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan endTime { get; set; }

        public ArticoliFascia(string codart, string desc, int qta, decimal importo)
        {

            this.codart = codart;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.qta = qta;
            this.importo = importo;

            string[] splitArray = codart.Split(new char[] { '-' }).ToArray();
            startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(splitArray[0]);
            endTime = TimeSpan.Parse(splitArray[1]);
        }
    }
}
```